# How to send fixed current date from html forum to php file

Tags: php, html

I want to know is there any option through which I can send current date to a PHP forum.

Soon I tried it from sending it using html form value attribute,
but alas I fail here is my code which I tried:

```
<input name="date" type="text" id="signup_date" size="30"  
 value=" <?php date(Y/M/D) ?> ">
 <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"> 
 <input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset">
```

Any idea which I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your code with the one below:

```
 <input name="date" type="text" id="signup_date" size="30" value="<?php echo Date('Y/M/D', time()); ?>">
 <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"> 
 <input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset">
```

I strongly suggest, however, that you get the date on the server side when the form is submitted, rather than using an input field for this purpose.

Comment: this will give `2015/Mar/Thu`, you better use 'Y/m/d' to get `2015/03/19`